# ArcGIS network analyst JavaScript API "No Facility found" error

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, network-analyst

I am using below code for ArcGIS SERVER Network Analyst API:
[ArcGIS JavaScript API for Network Analyst](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/routetask_closest_facility.html)

I need to customize it for my own NA server. I have successfully created an NA-SERVER on ArcGIS for Server. 
This is url of my NA-SERVER.
http://10.1.250.33/arcgis/rest/services/demos/NetworkFacilities/NAServer/Closest%20Facility

But whenever I try to find the route  it gives me error, that no facilities were found. 
Below is my complete code. Please help me to figure out why this error is occurring. I am using facilities points specified in javascript code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-    scalable=no">
  <title>Closest Facilities</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style> 
      body,html,#main{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;width:100%;}
      .panel {
      border-radius: 6px;
      box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px -3px #888;
      border: 2px solid #86942A;
      margin: 5px;
    }
  </style> 

  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/"></script>
  <script>
    var map, params;
    require([
      "dojo/dom",
      "dojo/_base/array",
      "esri/Color",
      "dojo/parser",
      "dijit/registry",

      "esri/urlUtils",
      "esri/map",
      "esri/lang",
      "esri/graphic",
      "esri/InfoTemplate",
      "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
      "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",

      "esri/geometry/Point",
      "esri/tasks/FeatureSet",

      "esri/tasks/ClosestFacilityTask",
      "esri/tasks/ClosestFacilityParameters",

      "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
      "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",

      "dijit/form/ComboBox",
      "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
      "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
    ], function(
      dom, array, Color, parser, registry,
      urlUtils, Map, esriLang, Graphic, InfoTemplate, GraphicsLayer, SimpleRenderer, 
      Point, FeatureSet, 
      ClosestFacilityTask, ClosestFacilityParameters, 
      SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol
    ) {
      var incidentsGraphicsLayer, routeGraphicLayer, closestFacilityTask;

      parser.parse();



      map = new Map("map", { 
        basemap: "streets", 
        center: [73.147884,33.534415],
        zoom: 14, 
        showInfoWindowOnClick: false 
      });

      map.on("click", mapClickHandler);

      params = new ClosestFacilityParameters();
      params.impedenceAttribute= "Miles";      
      params.defaultCutoff= 7.0;      
      params.returnIncidents=false;
      params.returnRoutes=true;
      params.returnDirections=true;

      map.on("load", function(evtObj) {
        var map = evtObj.target;
        var facilityPointSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
          SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 
          20,
          new SimpleLineSymbol(
            SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new Color([89,95,35]), 2
          ),
          new Color([130,159,83,0.40])
        ); 

        var incidentPointSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
          SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 
          16,
          new SimpleLineSymbol(
            SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new Color([89,95,35]), 2
          ),
          new Color([130,159,83,0.40])
        );  

        incidentsGraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

        var incidentsRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(incidentPointSymbol);
        incidentsGraphicsLayer.setRenderer(incidentsRenderer);
        map.addLayer(incidentsGraphicsLayer);

        routeGraphicLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

        var routePolylineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(
          SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 
          new Color([89,95,35]), 
          4.0
        );
        var routeRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(routePolylineSymbol);
        routeGraphicLayer.setRenderer(routeRenderer);

        map.addLayer(routeGraphicLayer);

        var facilitiesGraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        var facilityRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(facilityPointSymbol);
        facilitiesGraphicsLayer.setRenderer(facilityRenderer);

        map.addLayer(facilitiesGraphicsLayer);

        facilitiesGraphicsLayer.add(new Graphic(new Point(8142548.8067,3966078.9112,map.spatialReference)));
        facilitiesGraphicsLayer.add(new Graphic(new Point(8143221.8677,3965679.8092,map.spatialReference)));
        facilitiesGraphicsLayer.add(new Graphic(new Point(8142586.1548,3965339.1853,map.spatialReference)));
        facilitiesGraphicsLayer.add(new Graphic(new Point(8143196.4393,3966040.7799,map.spatialReference))); 
        facilitiesGraphicsLayer.add(new Graphic(new Point(8143734.6762,3965471.3665,map.spatialReference))); 
        facilitiesGraphicsLayer.add(new Graphic(new Point(8143961.4138,3965903.508,map.spatialReference))); 

        var facilities = new FeatureSet();
        facilities.features = facilitiesGraphicsLayer.graphics;

        params.facilities = facilities;
        params.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;

      });

      closestFacilityTask = new ClosestFacilityTask("http://10.1.250.33/arcgis/rest/services/demos/NetworkFacilities/NAServer/Closest%20Facility");

      registry.byId("numLocations").on("change", function() {
        params.defaultTargetFacilityCount = this.value;
        clearGraphics();
      });

      function clearGraphics() {
        //clear graphics
        dom.byId("directionsDiv").innerHTML= "";
        map.graphics.clear();
        routeGraphicLayer.clear();
        incidentsGraphicsLayer.clear();    
      } 

      function mapClickHandler(evt) {
        clearGraphics();
        dom.byId("directionsDiv").innerHTML= "";
        var inPoint = new Point(evt.mapPoint.x, evt.mapPoint.y, map.spatialReference);
        var location = new Graphic(inPoint);
        incidentsGraphicsLayer.add(location);

        var features = [];
        features.push(location);
        var incidents = new FeatureSet();
        incidents.features = features;
        params.incidents = incidents;

        map.graphics.enableMouseEvents();

        routeGraphicLayer.on("mouse-over", function(evt){
          //clear existing directions and highlight symbol
          map.graphics.clear();
          dom.byId("directionsDiv").innerHTML= "Hover over the route to view directions";

          var highlightSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([0,255,255],0.25), 4.5);
          var highlightGraphic = new Graphic(evt.graphic.geometry,highlightSymbol);

          map.graphics.add(highlightGraphic);
          dom.byId("directionsDiv").innerHTML = esriLang.substitute(evt.graphic.attributes,"${*}");
        });

        //solve 
        closestFacilityTask.solve(params, function(solveResult){
          array.forEach(solveResult.routes, function(route, index){
            //build an array of route info
            var attr = array.map(solveResult.directions[index].features, function(feature){
              return feature.attributes.text;
            });
            var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Attributes", "${*}");

            route.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
            route.setAttributes(attr);

            routeGraphicLayer.add(route);
            dom.byId("directionsDiv").innerHTML = "Hover over the route to view directions";
          });

          //display any messages
          if(solveResult.messages.length > 0){
            dom.byId("directionsDiv").innerHTML = "<b>Error:</b> " + solveResult.messages[0];
          }      
        },function(e){
            alert('assa');
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="claro">      
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" 
       data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:false" 
       style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;">

    <div id="map" 
         data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
         data-dojo-props="region:'center'" class="panel">
    </div>

    <div id="directions" 
         data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
         data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'" class="panel" 
         style="height:250px;">

      <b>Click the map to find routes for the
      <select id="numLocations" name="numLocations" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" value="1" style="width:60px;">
          <option selected="selected">1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
      </select> closest facilities to the input point.</b> 
      <div id="directionsDiv"></div>

    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try experimenting with the [`ClosestFacilityParameters`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/closestfacilityparameters-amd.html)

Especially the cutoff-parameter is important to define correctly. In your code the default cutoff value is 7.0. Network Analyst will not search for locations outside a 7 mile radius or locations where wich exceed 7 minute driving time.

If you take a look at the sample provided by Esri in [sandbox mode](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=routetask_closest_facility) you find out that changing this parameter will alter the Network Analyst search.